# Flutter-Ontap location is not in the path of image generated by CustomPainter

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, svg, flutter-custompainter

I am trying to get the properties of CustomPainter elements when tapped. However, the location generated by onTapUp is not within the path created by CustomPainter Path.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  Offset _tapPosition = Offset.zero;


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('Custom Paint Example'),
        ),
        body: GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (TapDownDetails details) {
            // Handle tap here
            print('Tap location: ${details.localPosition}');
            print('Tap location: ${details.globalPosition}');
            final RenderBox renderBox = context.findRenderObject() as RenderBox;
            final Offset localOffset = renderBox.localToGlobal(details.globalPosition);
            Offset customPaintPosition = renderBox.localToGlobal(Offset.zero);
            print(Offset.zero);

            if (isTapInsidePath(LinePainter.path_1, details.localPosition)) {
              print('Tapped inside path_1 at ${details.localPosition}');
              // You can add logic to get the color at the tap position if needed.
            }
            // _handleClick(details.localPosition); 
          },
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(
                color: Colors.black,
                width: 10.0,
              ),
            ),
            child: CustomPaintExample(),
          ),        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  bool isTapInsidePath(Path path, Offset tapPosition) {
    print (path.getBounds());
    print (path.computeMetrics());

    return path.contains(tapPosition);
  }
}

class CustomPaintExample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: CustomPaint(
        painter: LinePainter(),
        size: Size(300, 300),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class LinePainter extends CustomPainter {
   static final Path path_1 = Path()
    ..moveTo(167.309,177.39)
    ..cubicTo(180.907,163.368,200.541,152.36499999999998,213.487,149.762)
    ..cubicTo(170.764,142.488,175.079,155.056,167.309,177.39)
    ..close();


    
  // static final Path path_1 = Path();
  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    Paint paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blue
      ..strokeCap = StrokeCap.round
      ..strokeWidth = 5.0;

    // Define a set of lines to be drawn on the canvas
    List<Offset> points = [
      Offset(50, 50),
      Offset(150, 100),
      Offset(100, 200),
      Offset(200, 250),
    ];

    // Draw lines on the canvas
    for (int i = 0; i < points.length - 1; i++) {
      canvas.drawLine(points[i], points[i + 1], paint);
    }


   
   Paint paint_1_fill = Paint()..style=PaintingStyle.fill;
    paint_1_fill.color = Color(0xff000000).withOpacity(1.0);
    canvas.drawPath(path_1,paint_1_fill);

  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return false;
  }
  
}
```

I have checked that the offset is 0. I have also checked the path.bounds(), which did not seem right. Below is the code.
Location when tapped: flutter: 256.3333282470703‘ and 527.0
Bounds from path_1: Rect.fromLTRB(167.3, 142.5, 213.5, 177.4)

I have used global location as well.